# Create a login role for postgres using pam madule

Tags: postgresql, pam

I have Postgresql DBMS installed on my Linux Mint 17.2 server. I already have a server login role for postgres user :

```
CREATE ROLE postgres LOGIN
  ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'md524bb002702969490e41e26e1a454036c'
  SUPERUSER INHERIT CREATEDB CREATEROLE REPLICATION;
```

Also, I installed pamusb module on server. I need to add one more pamusb role for this user. I'm going to create a two factor authentication.